# NVI for virtual function implemented in every layer of a deep hierarchy

Tags: c++, architectural-patterns

Suppose we have the following class hierarchy:

```
class Object {
public:
    virtual void update() {
        // Update position
    }
};

class Rocket : public Object {
public:
    virtual void update() {
        Object::update();
        // Orientate towards target
    }
};

class SparklingRocket : public Rocket {
public:
    virtual void update() {
        Rocket::update();
        // Create sparkling particles
    }
};
```

For obvious reason this is no good idea. For instance an inheritor of any of the classes might forget to call Base::update() and the behaviour of the program would be incomplete.
As I see it, functions that implement important behaviour shouldn't be made virtual, that's something better reserved for replaceable behaviour.

So, we would probably change the architecture like that:

```
class Object {
public:
    void update() {
        // Update position
        afterObjectUpdate();
    }

protected:
    virtual void afterObjectUpdate() {}
};

class Rocket : public Object {
protected:
    virtual final void afterObjectUpdate() override {
        // Orientate towards target
        afterRocketUpdate()
    }

    virtual void afterRocketUpdate() {}
};

class SparklingRocket : public Rocket {
protected:
    virtual final void afterRocketUpdate() {
        // Create sparkling particles
        afterSparklingRocketUpdate();
    }
    virtual void afterSparklingRocketUpdate() {}
};
```

This is pretty much what I want:

- The public interface of all classes is only the non-virtual update() - method
- When that method is called it is ensured that every update()-"submethod" is called
- Even if the one inheritor forgets to call a afterUpdate() - method, the hierarchy is stable from the base class down. This way a API could ensure its own integrity whilst in the first codeexample it would have to rely on the user to call the Base::update() method

I dislike one thing though: The name of each class is part of the after...Update() methodname. That seems like codesmell to me.

I think the general goal of keeping virtual call hierarchies stable can't be that uncommon. What is the commonly applied solution that I didn't come across yet?

Answer (score 2):

Having such virtual call hierarchies in the first place is quite rare. Having an inheritance tree that is more than three levels deep is often already considered a code smell and having a method that can be extended in each level of the hierarchy is rare.
Those two combined makes your scenario extremely rare.

On the other hand, the architecture you came up with has many similarities to a repeated application of the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern. In the Template Method pattern, the base class implements an algorithm for which some steps are implemented by a derived class.

---

As you are having trouble coming up with good names for the `afterXXXUpdate` method, it could also be that inheritance isn't the right tool here. Call chains, such as between your `update` methods are also a hallmark of the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern. It might be worth to have a look at.